# How to get selection from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextpane

I want to find out which part of JTextPanel text is selected. Tried to call `JTextPane.getSelectionStart()` and `JTextPane.getSelectionEnd()`, but they always return same value that is equal to current caret position. 
What is my problem with that?

I would be thankful for any code exapmle that gets current selection.

Comment: Document, Caret and viewToModel, but for better help soonet post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: [I would be thankful for any code exapmle that gets current selection.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0240__JTextComponent.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem - that was a custom `FocusListener` which was changing JTextPane content (and so dropping the selection) before I got the `keyTyped` event.

Anyway, thanks everyone for examples and comments!

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [`JTextComponent#getSelectedText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29). You'd simply call this method on the instance of your `JTextPane`and it will return the selected text of your `JTextPane`. Did a small example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication101 {

    private JTextPane jTextPane;
    private JButton btnGetSelectedText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaApplication101().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(Container contentPane) {
        jTextPane = new JTextPane();
        btnGetSelectedText = new JButton("Get selected text");

        btnGetSelectedText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTextPane.getSelectedText());
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(jTextPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(btnGetSelectedText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TextPaneHighlightsDemo extends JFrame {

public TextPaneHighlightsDemo() {
    super("SplashScreen demo");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JTextPane textPane = new  JTextPane();
    add(textPane);
    textPane.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            Highlight[] h = textPane.getHighlighter().getHighlights();
            for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(h[i].getStartOffset());
                System.out.println(h[i].getEndOffset());
            }

        }
    });
        }

public static void main (String args[]) {
    TextPaneHighlightsDemo test = new TextPaneHighlightsDemo();
    test.setVisible(true);
}
}
```